# get computed height of div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a div that is positioned relative and then some divs inside that which are positioned absolute the parent div will have no height. The contents of the div can change though so I need a way to calculate the height of the contents and set the height of the parent dynamically. Is there a simple way to do this in jquery? See the following example:

http://jsfiddle.net/vgyrbcbs/

```
#parent {
    position: relative;
}
.child {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ff0000;
}  
#child1 {
    top:0;
    left:0
}
#child2 {
    top:50px;
    left:150px;
}
#child3 {
    top:150px;
    left:20px;
}
#child4 {
    top:250px;
    left:150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child" id="child1"></div>
    <div class="child" id="child2"></div>
    <div class="child" id="child3"></div>
    <div class="child" id="child4"></div>
</div>
```

How would I work out the height of the parent?

Comment: add the greatest top of any child to the height of child... ;)

Comment: parent height is obviously `0` :)

Comment: @A1rPun Absolutely positionned elements don't affect layout's flow

Comment: @A.Wolff Argh good call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/vgyrbcbs/2/

```
var height = 0;

$("#parent div").each(function () {
   height += parseInt($(this).css("height").split("px")[0]);

});

$("#parent").css("height", height);
```

**UPDATE**

You can check the last div if it's always at the bottom like this : http://jsfiddle.net/vgyrbcbs/4/

```
$("#parent").css("height", parseInt($("#parent div:last").css("top").split("px")[0]) + parseInt($("#parent div:last").css("height").split("px")[0]));
```

Comment: `height += $(this).height()` I write earlier in comments is simpler :)

Comment: Heh, last div is not always bottom

Answer (score 3):

The parent's height is actually 0 because all the elements are positionned absolutely. If you're looking for the height of the content, the `scrollHeight` property of the parent will give you that information.

```
$('#parent')[0].scrollHeight; // or
$('#parent').get(0).scrollHeight; // or
$('#parent').prop('scrollHeight');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var h = 0;
$('#parent .child').each(function(){h = Math.max($(this).offset().top + $(this).height(), h);})
alert(h);
```

I just search height as top+height of bottom child element

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgyrbcbs/3/)

Answer (score 0):

try to count the last div (child 4) offset top + child 4 height - parent offset top

try this

```
var parent_height = $('#child4').height()+$('#child4').offset().top-$('#parent').offset().top;
```